# Rails migration strategies on horizontally scaled apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aws-opsworks

Assume I have an OpsWorks Rails application running with load and time based scaling.

What happens if I deploy code where there are multiple application servers running, in which multiple `rake db:migrate` is executed across the application servers?

Does Rails have any guard against this? OR would I specifically need to specify a single server that is responsible for running the migrations?

I am also curious to hear about migration strategies for Rails + RDS (Postgresql) on AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **Yes, Rails had a guard against this situation**

First, the RDS itself can cache your queries. So for example, 2 of your instances running one `CREATE INDEX` query at the same time, the RDS itself can handle it.

Second, Rails automatically create a table named `schema_migrations`. When one of your instances running `db:migrate`, the table `schema_migrations` can help the other instances know that the database is already migrated up ( just like a version management system )

But, there is a bad practice that you wrote some custom queries in `db/migrate/***.rb` file, then your query might not be handled correctly by RDS.

If you have to do something like update data by custom domain, you should write a rake task and manually execute it.

So, if you only use `db:migrate` to update data structure, then everything already handled for you, even you had hundreds instances.

For more information, please refer [Rails's document](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)